# Bootstrap Resampling at a Group Level

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, scipy, statistics-bootstrap

Suppose you have a pandas data frame like below. How can you create bootstrap resamples based on `group_id` column.

So, what I would like to get is that create samples with replacement based on `group_id` then bootstrap data frame based on the selected groups.

```
       class  group_id 
0      1        1   
1      1        1  
2      1        1 
..     ..       ..
8      0        2 
9      0        2
```

Thanks

Comment: Should the number of samples per group stay the same?

Comment: @DataJanitor It should stay the same. Suppose that each row is an observation from the group specified by the `group_id`. I would like to keep all the observations within the group if the group is selected in the bootstrap sample.

Comment: Please show an example of calculating the desired statistic from the original DataFrame. Without that sort of information, there are many ways the question can be interpreted.